# Pyinstaller update problem not working and pyinstaller not found fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have pip installed and when I tried to install pyinstaller I get this message. (Run on Admin)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Stevie>ping http://ddos.networkchuck.com/
Ping request could not find host http://ddos.networkchuck.com/. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Stevie>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Stevie>pip install pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\stevie\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\stevie\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2020.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\stevie\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2019.4.18)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\stevie\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\stevie\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\stevie\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32"->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Stevie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I typed -m pip install --upgrade pip in the right directory to upgrade and I get an error saying

```
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> -m pip install --upgrade pip
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    -m pip install --upgrade pip
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

When I try to do pyinstaller in command prompt this happens:

```
C:\Users\Stevie>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Stevie>
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first try `pip freeze` to see if pyinstaller is installed by pip
If it is installed, try

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: I installed it again and I this happened:
WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Stevie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Comment: I think you have changed 'python path in Windows'. Try to fix this first.

Comment: And I also heard that pyinstaller does not work well with Windows rich directory, better install python in a simple directory without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Directly in the Command Prompt (NOT in the Python interpreter) type `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`